# USB-C OTG Cable/Connector Wiring

Tags: usb-c, otg

How is a USB-C OTG with only 2.0 support adapter wired? Here is an example of such an [adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07GNCBJL6). The VBUS, GND, D+ and D- pass to the USB-A receptacle but what happens to the CC pin? What ID resistors (if any) are used on the data lines?

Answer (score 1):

Per the USB-C spec, 5.1K to ground on each CC line.

For a discussion of what you need to do and what can go wrong, see the followup to the failure modes of the Raspberry Pi 4:  https://hackaday.com/2019/07/16/exploring-the-raspberry-pi-4-usb-c-issue-in-depth/